# Clickhouse JDBC version > 0.4.x fails in Cloud

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have to connect a java cloud application to clickhouse cloud database. The restriction is that the certificate cannot be uploaded to the cloud application.

clickhouse-jdbc version 0.3.2 works perfectly with this jdbc url:

```
jdbc:clickhouse://xxxxxx.aws.clickhouse.cloud:8443/dev?ssl=true&sslkey=xxxxxx&sslcert=xxxxxxxxx
```

The connection fails using any clickhouse-jdbc version above 0.4.x:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open file from: classpath:xxxxxx, server ClickHouseNode [uri=https://xxx.aws.clickhouse.cloud:8443/dev, options={sslmode=strict,key_store_type=*,sslkey=*,sslcert=xxxxxx}]@1390580080
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.handle(SqlExceptionUtils.java:85)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.create(SqlExceptionUtils.java:31)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.handle(SqlExceptionUtils.java:90)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.getServerInfo(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.<init>(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:335)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.<init>(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:288)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver.connect(ClickHouseDriver.java:157)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver.connect(ClickHouseDriver.java:41)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at com.onibex.connect.delta.jdbc.dialect.CommonDatabaseDialect.getConnection(CommonDatabaseDialect.java:154)
    at com.onibex.connect.delta.jdbc.connection.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:83)
    at com.onibex.connect.delta.jdbc.connection.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:55)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open file from: classpath:xxxxxx
    at com.clickhouse.data.ClickHouseUtils.getFileInputStream(ClickHouseUtils.java:981)
    at com.clickhouse.client.config.ClickHouseDefaultSslContextProvider.getKeyStore(ClickHouseDefaultSslContextProvider.java:104)
```

I have tried different combinations with these paramaters:

ssl=true/false

sslmode=strict/none

http_connection_provider=HTTP_CLIENT

But it is not working. Any idea what's the url for clickHouse-jdbc (com.clickhouse.clickhouse-jdbc) version > 0.4x to connect to clickhouse cloud without a certificate?

Comment: Why are you adding your own key and certificate to ClickHouse Cloud?  ClickHouse Cloud does not support using your own certs.  (Although I'm not sure why it worked with the older version).  In any case the error indicates that the certificate you are providing isn't available in the classpath of your application, so you need to make sure that your application classpath includes the certificate location.

Comment: it is not actually a file, I'm using sslkey=api-key and sslcert=api-secret, it works for version 0.3.2. Then the question is how to connect to clickhouse cloud using api-key with driver version > 0.4.x?

Comment: I would contact the ClickHouse support team, since I'm not sure why you would need any api keys or secrets with ClickHouse Cloud.  You would need username and password, so maybe somehow 0.3.2 was using those values as username and password instead?

Comment: The API key in your other stack overflow question is for accessing the ClickHouse Cloud API, which is not the same as your ClickHouse database service.  The API doesn't support JDBC, so you should be able to connect if you remove any reference to api keys or secrets in your connection string and just use username and password.